# Drupal8 views broken handler with custom entity type

Tags: views, entities, 8

I'm building a **Bet website** a long test of Drupal 8.

Thanks to drupal console I managed to create a lot of custom entity types.

Now I want to expose my entity to views but I get this message;

[image: The handler for this item is broken or missing. The following details are available:]

One of the only customization I've done from my **game** entity type was to change the table name : from **game** to **mespronos_game**, by editing the annotation from :

```
base_table = "game"
```

to

```
base_table = "mespronos__game"
```

This is working, I'm able to create game entities but I can't figure how to tell views the table he should look in.

Here's all the annotation for my game entity :

```
/**
 * Defines the Game entity.
 *
 * @ingroup mespronos
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "game",
 *   label = @Translation("Game entity"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\mespronos\Entity\Controller\GameListController",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\mespronos\Entity\GameViewsData",
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\mespronos\Entity\Form\GameForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\mespronos\Entity\Form\GameForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\mespronos\Entity\Form\GameForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\mespronos\Entity\Form\GameDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\mespronos\GameAccessControlHandler",
 *   },
 *   base_table = "mespronos__game",
 *   admin_permission = "administer Game entity",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid"
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/game/{game}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/game/{game}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/game/{game}/delete"
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "game.settings"
 * )
 */
```

All my sources files are available on github : https://github.com/kgaut/mespronos

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clear cache and run update.php so the schema can get updated.

Comment: Why did you rename the base table? If you want a prefix, Drupal supports that globally in settings.php